# What does "+" mean in cpp lambda declaration "auto fun1 = +[](){};"

Tags: c++, lambda, types, compilation, capture

I've seen in stackoverflow, people write lambda like this:

```
int main() {
    auto f1 = +[](){};    
    auto f2 = [](){};
    return 0;
}
```

(1) What does the `+` acturelly do in `f1` expression?
I tried to add capture, then `f1` doesn't compile, but the error is not readable to me:

```
    auto f1 = +[=](){};  // fail to compile
    auto f2 = [=](){};
```

The error is:

```
invalid argument type '(lambda at .\xxx.cpp:4:16)' to unary expression
    auto f1 = +[=](){};
```

(2) What does this error indicate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda has a compiler-generated type.  If you just assign the lambda as-is to an `auto` variable, then the `auto` variable's type will be deduced as the lambda's generated type.

A *non-capturing* lambda is **implicitly** convertible to a plain function pointer.  By placing `+` in front of the lambda, the lambda is **explicitly** converted to a function pointer, and then the `auto` variable's type will be deduced as the function pointer type, not the lambda type.

A *capturing* lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer at all, which is why you get the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

(1) It converts the lambda with no capture to function pointer.

(2) It indicates that you are about to capture by value, in which case conversion to function pointer is not possible.